# Adding 2 favorite tags at one time combines tag after page refresh

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching

I was adding some tags to my favorite tags today and noticed tags being joined together when the page is refreshed.

Steps to reproduce:

- Click edit on Favorite Tags
- Create the first tag and click add [I added `django` in this case]
- Add a second tag and click add [I added `python` in this case]
- Refresh page
- Favorite tags now show previous tags + `djangopython`

In the edit section, it appears as if the tags are added separately, but when I refresh the page they get joined

OS: MacOSX-10.8

Browser: Chrome, Firefox

Comment: Just reproduced it using Ubuntu 12.04 and both Chrome and Firefox. Tested with a different pair of tags and still reproduced it.

Comment: Likewise, reproduced it using Chrome on Mac OS X.

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox 22 and Chrome 30 on Windows 8 with different tags.

Comment: The bug is in the JavaScript constructing the string being sent in AJAX, resulting in [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mMIaC.png). If you add tags to favorites using the hover popup it's working fine when adding more than one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While internationalizing the javascript around saving preferred tags, errors were made andspaceswereforgotten.

Tagmergingensued.

**This is now fixed** andwillbedeployedinthenextbuild.

Comment: I don't need JavaScript to do this, my keyboard already does this for me perfectly well.