# Static tag glitch

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-watching

I did something stupid, and now I can't remove a tag from my favorite tags list.

I was curious to see if I could use a tag like `[css] or [html]`. However, it appears that there is some sort of a glitch if you use the word `or` as a tag.

**Steps the reproduce** – *although you will end up with a tag that is un-removable*.

- Go to preferences.
- Go to "Favorite tags" and paste in something like: `[css] or [html]`.

  > [image]
- Click <kbd>Add</kbd>, and you will get something like:

  > [image]
- Refresh the page and the `or` tag will become static and un-removable.

  [image]

I tried removing all the tags, but that didn't do anything. Now the word `or` just falls before all the other tags.

I have tried reproducing this with words other than `or`, however `or` seems to be the only known word that will do this. I was able to reproduce the same glitch with the ignored tags too.

> [image]

In the HTML, it is rendered as `or&nbsp;`

> [image]

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce here on Meta or on [so].

Comment: @Oded That's weird... Are you able to go in my account and look at it?

Comment: No, I can't, even as a dev. Try clicking outside the edit area (so it is not active), then the edit link to get the delete options and delete the tag. If this still fails, can you confirm the browser and OS you are using?

Comment: I can reproduce it. Create the tag, then refresh the screen.

Comment: @Oded Still can't remove it - I am using Chrome, Version 30.0.1599.69 m .. on a Windows 7.

Comment: OK. The extra step to repro was posted by @dcaswell

Comment: @Oded That step was in the original post ;)

Comment: @JoshC - And I missed it ;)

Comment: @joshC I figured out how to remove it, should I post it as an answer?

Comment: @dcaswell Sure.

Comment: @Oded is this the space Mr. Cecconi [added recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200269/152859)? ;-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - may very well be

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Enter this as your favorite tag `[css] or [html]`
2. click add
3. refresh screen

For all of us who have messed up our tags after reproducing Josh's issue:

Click `edit` next to your favorite tags

This is  the HTML generated in Chrome for my tags.

```
<div id="interestingTags"><a href="/questions/tagged/sql" class="post-tag user-tag" title="show questions tagged 'sql'" rel="tag">sql<span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span></a> <a href="/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008" class="post-tag user-tag" title="show questions tagged 'sql-server-2008'" rel="tag">sql-server-2008<span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span></a> <a href="/questions/tagged/css" class="post-tag user-tag" title="show questions tagged 'css'" rel="tag">css<span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span></a>  or&nbsp; <a href="/questions/tagged/html" class="post-tag user-tag" title="show questions tagged 'html'" rel="tag">html<span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span></a> </div>
```

Note that `or` is my second to last pseudo-tag.

Delete this HTML  `or&nbsp;` using the `edit html` option in Chrome Tools:

Delete your last tag . In this case it's the `HTML` tag.

Refresh your screen.

No more `or` tag.

Answer (score 7):

or  and  and  are used as conjunction in search and other displays and thus should not be used in tag preferences.

I've fixed the code so it removes them if you try to insert them, and does not display them if you have them.

This change will be deployed in the next build out.